# Which Marvel character had a bomb in his heart which would explode when his heart stopped?

Tags: marvel, avengers, character-identification

I remembered a Marvel Comics story I read a while ago. I read it in the 90s but I think it had been published long before that, any time between the 60s and 80s.

It was a story of a superhero team. I think they were the Avengers but may have been the X-Men or another team.

The story was about a guy who had planted a lot of bombs around the world, strong enough to destroy the planet, and the team were trying to find them. It turned out that the "bombs" were actually more like tape recorders and when brought together they played a recording that explained the real bomb was in the guy's heart, and if his heart stopped the bomb would explode.

Their solution was to put him in some kind of cryo sleep, so that while he was effectively dead and couldn't threaten the world his heart would keep beating and keep the bomb from exploding.

I'm looking for the name of that character so that I can find out if a "better" resolution was ever found or if he's still there in main Marvel canon.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Jason Beere (Earth-616).**

He appeared in *Avengers #169*, which was published in March 1978. Here’s his [History from the Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Jason_Beere_(Earth-616)), which matches your description almost completely:

> Jason Beere was a wealthy industrialist, worth over 200 million dollars, and one of Tony Stark's major competitors. He was diagnosed with a terminal disease and given six months to live. Frustrated that his vast wealth would be unable to save his life, he decided that if he should die, the world must die with him. He used a portion of his wealth to implant a powerful neutron bomb within his chest. He also had a suit of armor built for himself, and then had three what-appeared-to-be bombs placed in three locations around the world: in Peru, among a bird-worshipping tribe; in the Arctic Circle, within the cave of an immense polar bear; and in Moscow, within a museum. Beere forewarned the Russians and the bird-worshipping tribe that American heroes would be coming to steal the bombs, and convinced them to make every effort to stop them.
>
> Wearing his armor, Beere then broke through a wall at Avengers Mansion and ambushed the Avengers there: the Black Panther, Captain America, and Iron Man. He attacked them savagely, attempting to force them to kill him, but Iron Man succeeded in subduing and unmasking him. Beere threatened them that the world would die when he did, and warned them of four bombs around the world. Iron Man flew Beere to his Stark International facility, where he used his original chest plate to stabilize Beere's failing heart.
>
> The Avengers went after the three bombs in Peru, the Arctic Circle, and Moscow, and succeeded in retrieving them. However, upon examining the ‘bombs', Iron Man determined that there were no explosives within them. The Avengers linked the three devices together, and they played out Beere's last message, revealing the bomb within his chest, set to detonate when his heart stopped. Iron Man then placed Beere within a cryogenic chamber, where his heart would be slowed, but would never stop due to the chest plate.

The Marvel Wikia doesn’t note any further developments in his story: there’s a footnote about his mention in *Avengers: Roll Call #1*, in which they comment on his situation:

> The Avengers noted the irony that Beere feared to die young, but now might live forever: an Eternity Man.

but it doesn’t mention any other appearances, and I can’t find anything to suggest he shows up in any alternative universes or storylines.

Comment: And it seems he's supposed to be still there! I had thought that over several decades some writer would have decided to give a more permanent solution. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @GeorgeT nothing in comics is permanent.

Comment: @Pureferret As they say, no one in comics stays dead except Bucky, Jason Todd, and Uncle Ben.

Comment: [except Uncle Ben](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_death#Notable_examples)

Comment: I wonder where they're keeping the cryogenic chamber. Both Avengers Mansion and Stark Tower have been destroyed multiple times since then...

Comment: Goven that his only appearance was in a fill-in story, it's even less likely that anyone will pick up on it.

Comment: Why put him in cryo-sleep? Just put him in a remote Nevada desert or the ocean and let him light it up. His heart bomb can't be more power than the nukes already tested in the desert & ocean. Or launch him into the sun. Etc